# Half-wavelength lossless transmission: magnetic energy and electric energy balance

Tags: transmission-line

I'm studying transmission lines and came up with a problem about a lossless transmission line that has a length equal to half the wavelength of the line.

My book computes the complex power at the lines generator and it comes up with pure imaginary number. That means active power is zero and reactive power is non-zero.

Now, from Poynting Complex Theorem that means that the Joule power dissipation is zero (makes sense because this is a transmission line) and that the difference between the average magnetic energy and the average electric energy inside the line is non-zero.

However, my book remarks that the average magnetic energy is equal to the average electric energy through the line because the line has a length equal to half the wavelength.

How is that physically possible since we have a non-zero reactive power? Am I missing something? Is the book trying to imply some thing else related to a half-wavelength transmission lines?

I would like to have some clarification please.

Comment: A few paragraph breaks would avoid the wall of text look to your question. Use 2 x Enter.

Comment: @Transistor Done ;)

Comment: Anyone??????????